# Redirects only the main shop page (excluding search) to another page in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I tested following code to redirect my shop main page to an another page, home.

It works but it also redirects search result to home so people can't see the search result.

```php
add_action('template_redirect', 'bc_010101_redirect_woo_pages');
function bc_010101_redirect_woo_pages() {
    if (is_shop())
   {
     wp_redirect('/');
     exit;
   }
}
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add [is_search()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_search/) to your if condition, which determines whether the query is for a search.

So you get:

```php
function action_template_redirect() {   
    /**
     * is_shop() - Returns true when on the product archive page (shop).
     * is_search() - Determines whether the query is for a search.
     *
     * (redirect to home)
     */
    if ( is_shop() && ! is_search() ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'action_template_redirect' );
```

OR as a product search adds **'s'** query variable in URL, you can try to use:

```php
function action_template_redirect() {   
    /**
     * is_shop() - Returns true when on the product archive page (shop).
     *
     * (redirect to home)
     */
    if ( is_shop() && ! isset( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'action_template_redirect' );
```